# Get the Class Name of a Field from reflection

Tags: java, reflection

Im going round in circles on this.

I have a class Person, eg

```
public class Person {
String name = "";
}
```

Now, I would like to introspect this class instance & figure out what Class is name declared as.

So, name = String or java.lang.String

This is my Code:

'this' is an instance of Person.

```
try {
    String className = this.getClass().getName();
        Class cls = Class.forName(className);
        Field fieldlist[] = cls.getDeclaredFields();
        for (int i = 0; i < fieldlist.length; i++) {
           Field fld = fieldlist[i];
           int mod = fld.getModifiers();
           System.out.println("1. " + fld.toGenericString());
           System.out.println("2. " + fld.getName());
           System.out.println("3. " + fld.getGenericType() + "]");



           Object oj = fld.getType();

           // Says that 4: class java.lang.String

           System.out.println("4: " + oj.toString());
           Class c1 = oj.getClass();

           // Should throw Exception
           String stype = c1.getDeclaringClass().toString();
           System.out.println("5. " + stype);


        }
      }
      catch (Throwable e) {
         System.err.println(e);
      }
```

I managed to get to a part that states:

class java.lang.String

but I need it to be "java.lang.String"

Any ideas?

Comment: It is giving this as in the Class class's toString method it is written like that "class Your class name"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try.. getType() and then getName()

```
 fld.getType().getName()
```

Edit:(Aften Green Days' comment) -- Note that 
`fld.getType().getCanonicalName()` will give same output in most cases. The output is different when innerclasses are used. Here is [link](http://www.cognitus.net/html/tutorial/reflection/sec_2_1.html) came from search.  Depending what you need to do with classname you may choose one of getName() or getCanonicalName()

Comment: Thanks guys, but .getName() is more reliable in the case im working.

Answer (score 2):

```
System.out.println("3. " + fld.getType().getCanonicalName());
```

results in:

```
3. java.lang.String
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess I solved it,

Should have done this:

```
String stype = fld.getType().getName();
```

Answer (score -1):

I got the class name of a field by calling this
f.getDeclaringClass().getSimpleName()

Comment: That's actually incorrect as `f.getDeclaringClass()` returns type of class where the field has been declared and not the field type itself. `f.getType()` is the correct answer.