# how to check return type of method is JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

Could anyone help me find to check return type of a method is of specific type in JAVA. I tried this. But unfortunately it doesn't work. Please guide me.

```
Field[] fields = LanguageTranslation.class.getFields();

    for(Field f : fields ){
    System.out.println("Type is:"+f.getType()+"\t Name:"+f.getName());
      if(f.getType().equals(JLabel))
       {
                System.out.println("Field is of type "+f.getType());
             //other stuff
        }
```

Here f.getType() returns an object, I want to check weather it is a JLabel or not. If it is, I have other stuff to do. I tried above code , error is `JLabel cannot be resolved to a variable` I have declared one JLabel in class as `public JLabel testingText=null;` please help me in this

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example).

Comment: why are you using reflection? Make getter methods and access directly. Reflection makes the things slow.

Comment: I have to use reflection, because I dont knw what are the fields in class, if the field is of JLabel and JButton , I want to translate them to french language

Comment: Getting the fields of a class does not guarantee that they are initialised or that they won't be changed at some point in the future

Answer (score 0):

You can use `instanceof` to find out of which type an object is. But as you're using reflection, you first need to get the value of the field inside the object which you want to reflect. Example:

```
LanguageTranslation translation = ...; // Your object
Field[] fields = LanguageTranslation.class.getFields();

for(Field field : fields ){
    Object fieldValue = field.getValue(translation);

    if(fieldValue instanceof JLabel) {
        System.out.println("Field " + field.getName() + " of translation " + translation + " is a JLabel!");
    }
}
```

Comment: no it is showing error as `Incompatible conditional operand types Field and JLabe`

Comment: @user3218114 it is a array public fields used in class, I used reflection concept. it is a class `java.lang.reflect.Field;`

Comment: Then you need to use the `f.getValue(o)` method first, passing the object on which you reflected. Do you really want to use reflection?

Comment: Yes , because I dont knw what are the fields in class, if it is of JLabel and JButton , I want to translate them to french language.

Comment: @maxdev I didnt get What is parameter o here.

Comment: The object on which you initially used reflection. I'll update my answer.

Comment: `Field` and `JLabel` are not in same hierarchies. hence you can't use `isntanceof` operator. Try `Integer isntanceof String`

Comment: @maxdev Thank you but here I have `LanguageTranslation` as class .

Comment: @maxdev there is no method getValue() for Field type.

Comment: it is showing error as `The method getValue(LanguageTranslation) is undefined for the type Field`

Answer (score 0):

I never suggest you to use Reflection instead use getter method to access field directly.

If still there is no option other than Reflection then try

```
f.getType().getName().equals(JLabel.class.getName())
```

[Read more...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8921165/get-the-class-name-of-a-field-from-reflection)

Comment: Thanks dude , it worked but i didnt understand why Reflection is not good.

Comment: Read more [here](http://advint.extrapro.ru/articles/reflection.php) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/)

Comment: Could you maybe *not* accept an answer that does not answer the question and is incorrect? What @user3218114 wrote there does not help you, it is just a poor workaround for the `Incompatible types` problem.

Comment: You are using the name of the type of `f`, while `f` is of type `Field` (what you already know). OP wants the value of the field since hes using reflection, see my answer.

Comment: @maxdev you are right , it just solved for if condition but for my other stuff i need actual object.

Comment: +1 (maybe biased/unfair:-) because `for(Field f : fields ){` I'd be take `Class clz = f.getDeclaringClass();` as 1st. code line inside loop, then `if (clz.equals(Xxx.class)) {`, then to setAccesible, change the value, close (access to JList in JScrollPane for BasicComboBoxPopup)

Comment: @mKorbel OP is not interested in the actual value of the Field. As per the code OP just want to know about the Field Type.